# jquery undefined index: Error ajax POST and/or php script?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, post

hello i am creating chat widget which provide chat widget website. i have created it but i dont know in some website it is working but in some website it is not working at all. right now i am facing this issue Undefined index: data_type in C:\wamp\www\college\chat_service_provider\receive_msg.php on line 69pt?.
here is my code

```
$.ajax({
        url: "http://127.0.0.1/college/chat_service_provider/receive_msg.php",
        method: "POST",
        data: {
            data_type: 'userdata', //i have tried 'data_type'
            email: a,
            key: c
        },
        success: function(a) {
            b = a;
            alert(a);
        }
    })
```

andthe php code

```
echo $_POST["data_type"];
```

so in some website it is working properly and alert me userdata.
but in some website it returning me 
Undefined index: data_type in C:\wamp\www\college\chat_service_provider\receive_msg.php on line 69
so please help me to find this issue thank you.
now got the answer.
i have changed code.

```
$.post("http://127.0.0.1/college/chat_service_provider/receive_msg.php",
    {
        data_type: 'userdata',
        email: a,
        key: c
    },
   function(a) {
        b = a;
        alert(a);
    })
```

Comment: so now because of jquery issue. some time it is sending data using GET method. i search alot but cant working it with 'type' OR 'method' . so i changed the code like this
`$.post("http://127.0.0.1/college/chat_service_provider/receive_msg.php",
{
            data_type: 'userdata',
            email: a,
            key: c
        },
       function(a) {
            b = a;
            alert(a);
        })`

Answer (score 1):

Try using post instead:

```
var data = {"email" : email, "key":key}
$.post("demo_test.asp", function(data, status){
    alert("Email: " + data.key + " Key: " + data.key + "\nStatus: " + status);
});
```

Comment: this one is from w3shools. and i think $.post is smaller version or $.ajax. ajax provide more functionality than $.post. so i dont think this gonna work. i wrote above script is working fine in some website but in some website it is showing me undefined index.

Comment: so finally it is working i use this method thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Please use firebug and open up the console, when you do the Post request did "userdata" get sent over in the Post request?

Please troubleshoot from there.

Comment: as you see in above code i directly assign string 'userdata' to variable data_type so i think it will send that data.
but still i want to check it. i am not well known of firebug. so i find it difficult. so can you please guide me how can i do that. i have firebug.

Comment: Open up Firefox then go to the webpage you are sending data. Then right click on the page and open firebug. It will open up a separate window at the bottom. Click on the "console" tab. When you do a post action (button etc) it will show the post request.

Comment: hey i do it and yes it is sending. but on above i am getting this link

Comment: http://127.0.0.1/college/chat_service_provider/receive_msg.php?data_type=userdata&email=hello%40gmail.com&key=f4aca4a970b7ce4b5ed0464c86f9ba7c

it is for get requet right? but i have used post so why it is sending as get ?

Comment: If it's a post then it will be a post, not a get. I highly recommend you double check the codes for the actions to execute the code. Maybe loading a wrong file, of a wrong button ID etc. can't figure out with these codes on your question. They looks logically correct.

Comment: If that website is not working please make sure u use jquery higher than 1.9 else you need to substitute "method" with "type"

Comment: type (default: 'GET') Type: String An alias for method. You should use type if you're using versions of jQuery prior to 1.9.0.

Comment: i have tried both "type" and "method" but same result so at the last have changed my method $.ajax to $.post
$.post is working fine. thank you